# PHP echo output without delay?

Tags: php, echo

Quick and dirty: Is it possible to let php send each output back to the browser immediately? Right now when I run it it seems to either wait for different tranches to be filled or for the script to be completely executed.

If so, does it compromise performance?

Comment: Are you using a full PHP script like a CMS? Or is it just <?php echo 'hello world'; ?>?  It seems like there is a lot being loaded at once, hense the delay

Comment: What do you mean? That's PHP's default behaviour. The behaviour where PHP only sends all the output after the script finishes executing is only possible if output buffering is turned on.

Comment: Sorry, I'm outta suggestions then,  I never have any delays when loading a PHP script. It makes the PHP query hthen it is returned in a HTML format, it doesn't 'delay' for me anyway, it may be a INI setting? But I would listen to ceejayoz, he has 59.8k points lol! Good luck

Comment: Fair disclosure, @PeterStuart: some of my points come from answers like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590902/please-help-make-3d-images-in-php :-p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`flush()`](http://php.net/flush), but whether it'll do anything is up to other parts of your stack - web server, any caching servers, etc.

Comment: +1 Typically you also have to send at least 4K of output before `ob_flush`/`flush` will have any effect.

Comment: i think you can set the value of the output buffer size you want

Comment: @ceejayoz Thank you! I read the documentation on flush(), but I am not really sure how to use it. Do I just put it at the beginning of the script?

On the other hand, I know that running a php script from my Shell does echo the output immediately. However, it doesn't work when I try to connect to a db in the database - how can I fix that? I am also happy to run the script in the Shell.

Comment: You call it whenever you want the output thus far dumped. You could put it after every `echo` statement, or before a particularly slow function, etc.